# What happens at the directory level when you move a file in a Windows command shell?

Tags: windows, shell

For a bit of background, I've got a directory on a server that is constantly having files delivered to it over time. The directory has become really big and I'm moving files out of the directory. I'm curious and not sure the best way to search for the answer so thought I'd ask here.

When I do a simple move command in a windows command shell, move * ..\Backlog\, for example, what happens? Specifically I mean, does Windows create something like an array of files at the moment you hit enter and just move those files? Or does it recreate the array of files every time a file is moved? I'm honestly just looking to learn how this works behind the scenes. If files are coming into the directory at a steady rate, are those going to get picked up by the move command even if they come in after you've executed it but while it's still running? Hopefully my question makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When you call "move" files are not actually moved on a disk, only the directory listing (which is effectively a file with some addresses associated with filenames) is changed.

I'm pretty sure that when you call `move * dest`, the `*` gets resolved at once and all of the files at that very specific moment in time are moved.  Anything that goes into that directory during the process is not included in the move.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was wondering. And you're of course correct, I had forgotten that moving was just a link change of sorts, not actually a move, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: I don't know what CMD's upper limit is for listing the target files before it starts moving them. I tried moving 10,000 files and didn't hit the limit. It first listed them all via `NtQueryDirectoryFile` before it started opening and moving them via `NtOpenFile` and `NtSetInformationFile`.

Comment: Also, it isn't necessarily the case that a relative move to  "..\Backlog" will just be a re-link within a single volume. "Backlog" might be a mounted volume.